# Extracting line of text from csv file with PowerShell by matching a pattern at the beginning of the line

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a CSV file that I need to extract a specific pattern that occurs at the beginning of a line such as:

Line of text:

```
"555555","A",John"
```

This works:

```
Get-Content $CsvFile | Select-String '^"555555"'
```

This does not:

```
$idnum = "555555"
Get-Content $CsvFile | Select-String '^"$idnum"'
```

How do I extract the line when the string is assigned to a variable?

Comment: ``(Get-Content $CsvFile) -match "^`"$idnum"``. With that said, please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need the extracted line for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single-quote in powershell is a literal. So in the second, you're explicitly looking to match *"$idnum"*. Because you've got double-quotes in your data you'll need to work around them.

**Options**
You can build up double-quotes to get around this

```
Get-Content $CsvFile | Select-String "^""$idnum"""
```

Or you can format in a string replacement like this:

```
Get-Content $CsvFile | Select-String ('^"{0}"' -f $idnum)
```

Or you can update $idnum to include the double quotes and then the select-string call is much easier to read

```
$idnum = '"555555"'
Get-Content $CsvFile | Select-String "^$idnum"
```